# Calculating percentage over sub query SQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table that records events regarding email campaigns. I want to figure out the percentage of campaigns where there was more than one event happening for the campaign.

First I calculated the number of events happening in each campaign:

```sql
select count(*) as counter
               from campaigns_log
               where event IN ('send', 'open')
                 and campaign_id is not null
               group by campaign_id, email
```

Then I grouped the campaigns in the condition whether more than one campaign happened:

```sql
select count(counter) as occurences, IF(counter > 1, 2, 1) as grouper
         from (select count(*) as counter
               from campaigns_log
               where event IN ('send', 'open')
                 and campaign_id is not null
               group by campaign_id, email) as counters_table
         group by grouper
```

Sample result:

```
occurences ¦ grouper
132        ¦ 1
360        ¦ 2
```

Now I want to calculate for each row the percentage of total occurrences. So something like this:

```
occurences ¦ grouper ¦ percentage
132        ¦ 1       ¦ 132/(132+360)
360        ¦ 2       ¦ 360/(132+360)
```

I tried this, but it does not work, it does not properly calculate the sum total:

```sql
select *, occurences/(select sum(occurences))
from (
         select count(counter) as occurences, IF(counter > 1, 2, 1) as grouper
         from (select count(*) as counter
               from campaigns_log
               where event IN ('send', 'open')
                 and campaign_id is not null
               group by campaign_id, email) as counters_table
         group by grouper
     ) as occurences_table group by occurences, grouper
```

Any idea where is my mistake in the last step?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, wrong tag, but the sentiment is the same. It does not really matter. It does for me but doesn't do what I need, so it does not matter. I need the last query that will produce the result I am looking for and described in the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated the tag appropriately.

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6 or similar with sample data that can be used to verify

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Please add the corresponding version-specific tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the secret is

```
SELECT  (...)/total, ...
    FROM campaigns_log
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM(...) AS total FROM ... ) x
```

That is, compute the total separately and make it available in the expressions.

Similarly:

```
SELECT @total := SUM(...) FROM ...
SELECT (...)/@total, ...
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem with your solution is that the `occurences_table` is not available in the `JOIN` expression, so I cannot calculate the total separately.

Comment: The same with the second solution I cannot assign to the variable select from a table that does not exist, but in only `in time` calculated as a part of the sub query.